# fcntl error with “mlflow ui” on windows - mlflow 1.0

Tags: python, windows, mlflow

I am getting the following error message when trying mlflow examples and running 'mlflow ui'.

**Error:**

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl' Running the mlflow server
>   failed. Please see the logs above for details

Is anyone aware of a solution to this issue?

I have tried the solutions suggested at https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/pull/1080

without success. Replacing the modified files in mlflow source code, it raises other issues for not finding what it is looking for with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\Scripts\mlflow.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\cli.py", line 198, in ui
    _run_server(backend_store_uri, default_artifact_root, "127.0.0.1", port, None, 1)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\server\__init__.py", line 90, in _run_server
    exec_cmd(full_command, env=env_map, stream_output=True)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\process.py", line 34, in exec_cmd
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\thesis_mlflow\lib\subprocess.py", line 1017, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved the issue: for some reason, waitress was not installed in the running environment. After installing it, everything seems working fine with the solution #1080 linked above in the question.

Comment: I have the same issue. I installed waitress and gunicorn but the issue still occurs

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following installation before executing the mlflow ui command:
pip install waitress